# Is it possible to scroll only one section of a UITableview and disable others?

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, sections

Suppose I have 3 sections in a TableView. I want to have scroll enabled to section at index 1 only by keeping a default height to it. Is this achievable ?

Comment: Why do you need the remaining 2 sections if you don't want to let the user scroll through them? Wouldn't it be easier to just not show them at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by composing two independent `UITableViews` together.

The first one displays your first section and has a fixed frame height. Inside this `UITableView` scrolling will be enabled and possible just as usual.

Below that `UITableView`, simply add another one. You can do this e.g. in the storyboard by constraining them to each another (first one's bottom equals second one's top). That second `UITableView` will display the two remaining sections and you can set a flag to disable scrolling and there you are!

One problem I see is that (especially on smaller devices) there might not be enough space left in the second `UITableView` to display the entire content. A workaround for that could be to constraint the upper `UITableView` to a height that equals exactly `the view's total height` **minus** `The content size of the second UITableView`. You would have to do that programmatically, though.

I hope you get the idea, if not just let me know and I will try to provide screenshots.

-- EDIT --

Maybe I got your question wrong. If you want to have the **middle** section scrollable you could either use the same approach but with even *three* `UITableViews` or consider adding simple `UIViews` above and below the `UITableView`. You would have to move the content out of your `UITableViewCells` to these views, then.

Another idea that comes to my mind are `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews`. You can queue whatever `UIView` you want to have sticky above a section as a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

As you can see, there's even plenty of options there :)

Comment: @fazeel ahamaed did that help you? Do you have questions on this? Do you need further help?

Comment: yes it help me. Thank you so much for the suggestions.